# Would there be a well-known distribution for this problem?

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm trying to think of a distribution to model the following situation.

People enter a market having different beliefs. Two non-negative integers can represent the belief $G \in \{0,1,....\}$ and $B \in \{0,1,...\}$, the number of good and bad experiences in the past. Two experiences are assumed to be independent and exogenously given.

I need an excellent way to represent this combination of $(G,B)$ with a probability mass function that goes to zero if one of the numbers goes to infinity (or any other way to handle an extreme case).

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful!

---

I decided to stick with a binomial distribution where $Binomial(k,n,p)$ where $k$ is the number of $G$, $n$ the number of past visited occasions, which I should assume every potential customer has the same $n$, and $p$ to be the probability of a past visit being a good experience. I'm not sure if there is a better distribution than this.

Comment: What is the tag [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory) about?

Comment: I removed it, I suppose he didn't know that distribution theory is not for probability distribution

Comment: Wikipedia has page for list of probability distributions, discrete ones, with infinite support. E.g., Poisson. Making each $G$ and $B$ Poisson, given you want them to be independent, their joint is just a product of the marginals.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to stick with a binomial distribution where (,,)
where 
is the number of 
, 
the number of past visited occasions, which I should assume every potential customer has the same 
, and 
to be the probability of a past visit being a good experience. I'm not sure if there is a better distribution than this